# How to read audio files using tf.data.Dataset.from_generator

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.7, tf.keras

Tensorflow Version : 2.1.0

Model built using tf.keras

Graphics Card : Nvidia GTX 1660TI 6GB DDR6

CPU : Intel i7 9th Gen

Ram : 16 GB DDR4

Storage Disk : SSD (NVME)

I wrote a code to read audio files in batches in a multithread manner using tf.keras.Sequences with multiple workers, but the issue with that code is the CPU is not concurrently reading the next set of audio batches while training the GPU due to which the GPU is being only utilized upto 30 percent of its max capacity (Training time for an epoch is around 25 minutes).

So I decided to move to tf.data.Datasets.from_generator to use the existing generator function to read the batches in a more efficient manner. But that input pipeline is performing more bad (taking 47 minutes to train an epoch). I have attached the code that I used to read create the input pipeline. I have read the file names and their categories from an excel file and fed them to the generator and created the pipeline.

Even after after applying prefetch the pipeline was performing really worse.

Since this is the first time that I am using tf.data API, I would like some insights if I have made any mistakes or not.

This is my code to generate the batches.

```
# Function read the audio files
def get_x(file):

    data = []

    for i in file:
        audio, fs = sf.read(i, dtype="float32")
        data.append(audio[::2])

    data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
    data = np.expand_dims(data, axis=-1)

return data


def data_generator(files, labels, batchsize):
    while True:
        start = 0
        end = batchsize

        while start  < len(files): 
        
            x = get_x(files[start:end])
            y = np.array(tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(labels[start:end], num_classes=2), dtype=np.float32)

        yield x, y

        start += batchsize
        end += batchsize


# Get the tensorflow data dataset object to generate batches
def tf_data_dataset(files, labels, batch_size):

    autotune = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
                            data_generator,
                            output_types=(np.float32, np.float32),
                            output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([None, 16000, 1]), 
                                tf.TensorShape([None, 2])),
                            args=(files, labels, batch_size))

    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=autotune)

return dataset
```